# Reception of double sms

Tags: sms

I have a Samsung Galaxy Mini2 phone, with android 2.3.6.

Every time that I recieve a SMS, 10 minutes after the reception I recieve it again. Do you know why??

I have installed only the built-in app for SMS. It happens for the 90% of SMS.

Comment: Do you have two different SMS apps installed? Does it happen every time? It *could* be the carrier (network) also... It's hard to know. Did this recently start happening?

Comment: I have installed only the built-in app for sms. It happens for the 90% of sms.

Comment: The last time I had this it was an error with the carrier, it might be worth asking them if it's a know issue? Failing that, then we'll have to dig into the phone software. You could try using Hangouts as your SMS app or another SMS application and see if that helps, there are many good free ones.

Comment: I can't use hangouts for sms. it works only for android 4.0 or grater

Comment: Ok, well see what SMS apps you **can** use and see if that helps, GO SMS used to be great, it's only for a test anyway. Failing that contact your Carrier and ask about it, they can also send you your APN settings if needs be.

Comment: Did the issue solve for you meanwhile? Remember, you always can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/192154) :)